# How do I groupBy a certain column in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to perfrom a groupBy on my database but I always get an error, Take a look at my code below

```
public function show($id){
  $building = Building::find($id);
  $offices = Office::where('building_id', $id)->get();
  return view('building')->with('building', $building)->with('offices', $offices)->groupBy('floor',$offices);
}
```

Comment: Show your error.

Comment: method [groupBy] does not exist on view

Answer (score 0):

groupBy needs to be called on $offices not on  the view.
Try this way:

```
public function show($id){
  $building = Building::find($id);
  $offices = Office::where('building_id', $id)->groupBy('floor')->get();
  return view('building')->with('building', $building)->with('offices', $offices);
} }
```

Also check out [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions)

Comment: its error
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'uniproject.offices.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `offices` where `building_id` = 1 group by `floor`)

Comment: I have 2 tables in my database 1 is for building and 2nd is for office

Answer (score 0):

First, yes, the groupBy needs to be added to offices.

Now, the other issue is problably a SQL_MODE problem. Check out your `config/database.php`, in the connection, change  `strict => false` like so:

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', ''),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,                       // strict to false   
        'engine' => 'InnoDB',
    ],
```

**Or....**

you can leave `strict => true` and add modes to mysql like so:

```
    'mysql' => [
        ...
        'strict' => true,           // keep strict true 
        'engine' => 'InnoDB',
        'modes' => [
            //'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', // disable this
            'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
            'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
            'NO_ZERO_DATE',
            'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
            'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
            'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
        ],            
    ],
```

You also could change the mode in MySQL. Check out the MySQL docs for more infos in this regard:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

And there was a pretty good explaination on laravel's modes here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14997#issuecomment-242129087

Hope that helps

Comment: I think it works but it only shows 4 data in that column, I have a lot of offices that belong on ground floor and so on...

Comment: its like this I have 5 offices in groundfloor ,6 offices in 2ndfloor , 5 offices in 3rdfloor, 3 offices in 4thfloor and it only shows 1 offices per floor

Comment: and when I try to create office it doesnt show in the web but its added in the database

Comment: what else we can do? @andi79h

Comment: If you `groupBy` floor, you end up having just one row per floor. That's exactly what grouping is about, and as your first question was, how to group floors, I thought you are ok now? What do you want to achieve then?

Comment: Oh I thought groupBy would organize data that I added.. ex. I add an office for Groundfloor I want it to be among the groundfloor not at the bottom cause everytime I add office it ends up  at the bottom.